# My attempt at proving $A\cup B=A \cup (B \cap A^{c})$

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification

This is my first time doing a proof where you have to show containment both ways. Is this proof correct?[image]

Comment: The implication $x \in B \implies x \in B \cap A^c$ is false. Also, for the sake of utter rigor, in the other containment you should say explicitly why both cases ($x \in A$ or $x \in B \cap A^c$) imply $x \in A \cup B$. I'd suggest that you use a venn diagram to illustrate to yourself why this result is true. If you draw this right, it's visually clear, and this will inform your proof.

Comment: @paulblartmathcop would you mind giving me a hint as to how I go about proving $A \cup B$ from the $x \in A$ case? In my drawing of the venn diagram, I see that I can generalize $x \in (A^c \cap B)$ to be $x \in B$, but that seems too similar to the $x \in B \cap A^c$ case.

Comment: I think a good way to approach this sort of problem is to think about these set theoretic operations in terms of logical formulas. For example, you correctly stated that $x \in A \cup B$ is the same as saying that $x \in A$ OR $x \in B$. Similarly, $x \in A \cap B$ is the same as saying that $x \in A$ AND $x \in B$ and $x \in A^c$ is the same as saying that $x$ is NOT in $A$. You are therefore asked to compare the logical statements $x \in A$ OR $x \in B$ vs. $x \in A$ OR ($x \in B$ AND $x$ not in $A$). Can you see why these statements are saying the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, not that you use it, but it's a bad idea for your first assumption to be the very thing you're trying to prove!

Secondly, you cannot say that, if $x \in B$, then $x \in B \cap A^c$. You've just assumed that $x \in B$, but it might also be true that $x \in A$ as well. What you should do is assume $x \notin A$. Then, since $x \in A$ or $x \in B$, then we must have $x \in B$. In this case, we have $x \in B \cap A^c$.

Otherwise, the proof looks fine!

Answer (score 1):

Your first step is wrong; $x\in(A\,\cup\,B)$ means that $x$ is in either or BOTH, hence when you say if $x\in B$, as you did, you should also specify that $x\notin A$. Clearly, if $x\in B$ and $x\in A$, then $x\notin (B\,\cap\,A^c)$.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the more complicated side (the right hand side in this case) and use the distributive and complement laws to get to the simpler side (the left hand side in this case) as follows:

$$A \cup (B \cap A^c)=(A \cup B) \cap (A \cup A^c)=(A \cup B) \cap U=A \cup B$$, where $U$ is the universal set (so $A,B \subseteq U$).

Comment: The op is asking for work verification and not for an alternative method "...my first time doing a proof where you have to show containment both ways."